# ASP.NET: Path.Combine with relative paths

Tags: asp.net, relative-path, absolute-path

I'm trying to convert "~/Uploads/Images/" to an absolute path I can create a FileStream from. I've tried VirtualPathUtility and Path.Combine but nothing seems to give me the right path. The closest I got was VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative, but that was just the file's location as a direct child of C:.

There must be a way to do this.

Comment: Do you want an absolute path or absolute url?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for the [`MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) method.

```
// get the path in the local file system that corresponds to ~/Uploads/Images
string localPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/Images/");
```

Use it together with Path.Combine to create a file path:

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(
                      HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/Images/"),
                      "filename.ext");
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
{
   // read the file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.Net Core MVC 6
This can be done as,

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment env;

    public YourController(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        this.env = env;
    }

    // Your action method for handling file upload
    public IActionResult UploadFile(IFormFile imgFile)
    {

        var virtualFilePath = Path.Combine("data/products/imgs", Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(imgFile.FileName));


        var webRootPath = env.WebRootPath;

       
        var imgFilePath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, virtualFilePath);

        // atomic transaction
        using (var stream = new FileStream(imgFilePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            imgFile.CopyTo(stream);
        }

       

        return RedirectToAction("UploadSuccess");
    }


}
```